# installing magento without control panel

Tags: php, apache, magento, centos

I want to install Magento on a fresh install of CentOS 5.5 without any control panel to help. So, AFAIK, I just need to install LAMP, right?

Apache:

```
yum install httpd
```

MySQL:

```
yum install mysql mysql-server mysql-php
```

PHP:

```
yum install php (possibly other modules too that magento might need)
```

Those are the only three things I need to install, right? However, PHP is outdated if I install from the base repo, so I need to install a newer PHP and perhaps newer MySQL. Is there anything I'm missing here? I'm not an expert on configuring MySQL from the command line, so should I install PHPMyAdmin? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are detailed requirements here:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/system-requirements

In general those are the three things you need. phpMyAdmin is extremely useful, which is probably why it is so popular, so is worth having.

Also remember to give the directories within Magento write permission and for a speed boost mount `var/cache/` as tmpfs.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy it to your server,
2. Edit `/app/etc/local.xml` and edit the DB settings.
3. And point your server to where you copied it. Magento (Enterprise) inserts all tables on the first time you call the website. Maybe your PHP max runtime has to be increased.